# Can two TcpClient connections to the same server (different ports) cause streaming issues

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Currently I have a program that creates 2 TCP clients that connect to different ports on the same server (This is not by choice and cannot be changed). However, I seem to have issues reading incoming messages on the client side. I am receiving/sending data just fine on the Listener's side.

[image: Visualisation]

This is the code for instantiating each client (this is through DPI) and reading data from it:

```
public class TcpClientHolder : ITcpClientHolder
{
    TcpClient _tcpClient;
    NetworkStream _networkStream;
    
    public void Open(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
    _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
              _tcpClient.Connect(_ipAddress, _port);
              _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
              _tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = _receivebuffersize;
              _tcpClient.SendBufferSize = _sendbuffersize;
              _tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
              _tcpClient.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 0);
              _tcpClient.LingerState.LingerTime = 0;
    }

    string ReadLine()
    {
        string _line = "";
        if (_networkStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            int _size = _networkStream.Read(receivebuffer, 0, _tcpClient.Available);
            _line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivebuffer, 0, _size);
        }
        else
        {
            // send empty packet every 2 seconds to detect socket error faster 
            if ((DateTime.Now - _lastKeepaliveSynchTime).TotalMilliseconds > _tcpKeepalivePeriod)
            {
                _logMan.WriteAll($"Sending Keepalive message or Empty Packet to server ");
                byte[] _data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");
                _networkStream.Write(_data, 0, _data.Length);
                _networkStream.Flush();
                _lastKeepaliveSynchTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I would like to know is twofold. Firstly, can the setup I have cause issues reading data on the client side. And if not, is there something code wrong in the code that is causing reading issues?

---

### EDIT

Additional information: I am creating two different clients from the same program. They are connecting to the same server/program, just using different ports. I wrote a simulator with two listeners on the same program/server, which handles these two client connections perfectly fine. I can receive data from each client individually and send data individually. However, the issue is on the client side when I want to read the data I am not getting any data available. No Error, just no available data to read.

Comment: How do you know your server can send data from those ports? What kind of error are you getting reading the data?

Comment: If the data sent from the server is without a client id then you must to create 2 different variables to store 2 tcp client instances, so you can distinguish which data you receive from port 1001 or port 1002.

Comment: Yeah... so you don't have two _tcpClient and two _networkStream instances? It's unclear from your code.

Comment: you can have one server port and accept multiple clients to connect

Comment: Another choice. If you use 1 port for multiple clients, you must send the client id along with data from the server, so that the client knows that the data is for itself and not for other clients based clent id.

Comment: @Train I wrote a simulator to check the network traffic. I am not getting an error, just that there is no data available for me to read.

Comment: `ReadLine()` We're going to have to see how and where you're using this code. It could be that `ReadLine()` is being called after there is no more data to read. Add a full example please.

Comment: Every TCP connection is characterised by *four* parameters - source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port. You don't normally need to use different ports on the server because the *source* port for the two clients will usually be left to be picked from the ephemeral port range on the client machine and will be different.

Comment: Your `ReadLine` has a fundamental mistake: it expects the `TcpClient` to always read a full packet. TCP is a streaming protocol, it has no understanding of lines or messages, so you need a framing protocol. For example, you can keep reading until you get a newline. Or you can wrap it in a `StreamReader` which can read a line at a time.

Comment: Also it looks like you have an infinite loop with no waiting. You should instead call `Read` with a `CancellationToken` or timeout, and if it cancels then you send an empty packet and wait again. This way you don't burn CPU. Another option is to just use the TCP keepalive option.

Comment: to answer your specific question - no its fine and should work. As others have said, you dont even need different ports on the server. YOu dont show all your code so is hard to say what your problem is. Usually its that people expect TCP to be message oriented

Comment: @pm100, yea seems that way. I did answer the question saying I wrote a different implementation that was more rebust and did work. Bpost your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class TcpClientWorker : IDisposable
    {
        protected static bool _endLoop = false;
        protected static Mutex _mutexEndLoop = new Mutex();
        protected static AutoResetEvent _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        protected static Thread _objThread = null;

        private TcpClient _tcpClient;
        private NetworkStream _networkStream;

        public TcpClientWorker()
        {
        }

        ~TcpClientWorker()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public bool EndLoop
        {
            get
            {
                bool result = false;
                _mutexEndLoop.WaitOne();
                result = _endLoop;
                _mutexEndLoop.ReleaseMutex();
                return result;
            }
            set
            {
                _mutexEndLoop.WaitOne();
                _endLoop = value;
                _mutexEndLoop.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            EndLoop = false;

            _objThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            _autoEvent.Set();

            while (EndLoop == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void KillThread()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_objThread != null)
                {
                    if (_objThread.IsAlive == false)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                EndLoop = true;

                if (_objThread != null)
                {
                    _objThread.Join();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                _objThread = null;
            }
        }

        public void WaitForThreadToStart()
        {
            _autoEvent.WaitOne();
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool bFreeAll)
        {
            KillThread();

            if (bFreeAll)
            {
                _mutexEndLoop.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                _mutexEndLoop.Close();
            }
        }


        public void Connect(string ipAddress, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_tcpClient == null)
                {
                    _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                }
                _tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);
                _tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                _tcpClient.SendBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                _tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
                _tcpClient.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 0);
                _tcpClient.LingerState.LingerTime = 0;

                _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_networkStream == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (_networkStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    _networkStream.Flush();
                }
                _networkStream.Close();


                if (_tcpClient == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (_tcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    _tcpClient.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public bool IsConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_tcpClient == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return _tcpClient.Connected;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void Write(String message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_tcpClient == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (_networkStream == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (_tcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    byte[] bMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    _networkStream.Write(bMessage, 0, bMessage.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public String Read()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_tcpClient == null)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                if (_tcpClient.Client == null)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                if (_networkStream == null)
                {
                    return "";
                }

                if (_tcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    if (_tcpClient.Client.Available > 0) {
                        byte[] bMessage = new byte[_tcpClient.Client.Available];
                        Int32 length = _networkStream.Read(bMessage, 0, bMessage.Length);
                        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bMessage, 0, length);
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

To call the above code as below

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpClientWorker _tcpClientWorker1;
        private TcpClientWorker _tcpClientWorker2;
        private Thread _clientThread1;
        private Thread _clientThread2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // connect to server via port 1001
            _tcpClientWorker1 = new TcpClientWorker();
            _clientThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_tcpClientWorker1.Run));
            _clientThread1.Start();
            _tcpClientWorker1.WaitForThreadToStart();
            _tcpClientWorker1.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1001);
            
            // send message to server via port 1001
            _tcpClientWorker1.Write("this message sent to 1001");

            // receive message from server via port 1001
            Debug.Print(_tcpClientWorker1.Read());

            // disconnect from server
            _tcpClientWorker1.Disconnect();
            _tcpClientWorker1.KillThread();



            // connect to server via port 1002
            _tcpClientWorker2 = new TcpClientWorker();
            _clientThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_tcpClientWorker2.Run));
            _clientThread2.Start();
            _tcpClientWorker2.WaitForThreadToStart();
            _tcpClientWorker2.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1002);

            // send message to server via port 1002
            _tcpClientWorker2.Write("this message sent to 1002");

            // receive message from server via port 1002
            Debug.Print(_tcpClientWorker2.Read());

            // disconnect from server
            _tcpClientWorker2.Disconnect();
            _tcpClientWorker2.KillThread();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `TcpClientHolder` for the OP is a  reusable class that creates a new client instance. This answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Train I changed the program to use a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong with the implementation, however, see the following I did which seperated read/write logic into a new thread.

```
public class TcpClientBase : ITcpClientBase
{
ILogMan logMan;

ConcurrentQueue<string> receivedQueue;
ConcurrentQueue<string> sendQueue;
TcpClient client;

public TcpClientBase(string address, int port, ILogMan logMan)
{
  this.logMan = logMan;
  this.receivedQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
  this.sendQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

  Thread thread = new Thread(() => HandleConnection(address, port));
  thread.Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// Handle any conenction to the device
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ip">Ip address</param>
/// <param name="port">Port</param>
void HandleConnection(string ip, int port)
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (CreateClient(ip, port, out client))
    {
      try
      {
        while (client != null && SocketConnected(client.Client))
        {
          if (client.Client.Available > 0)
          {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.Client.Available];
            client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            receivedQueue.Enqueue(message);
          }

          if (sendQueue.Count > 0 && sendQueue.TryDequeue(out string? toSend))
          {
            client.Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend));
          }
        }
      }
      catch
      {
        logMan.WriteError("Tcp Client encountered and error and disconnected...");
      }
    }

    // Attempt reconnect in 1 seconds
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Check if socket is connected
/// </summary>
bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
{
  bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
  bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
  if (part1 && part2)
  {
    IsConnected = false;
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    IsConnected = true;
    return true;
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Initialize the client and wrap it
/// </summary>
bool CreateClient(string ip, int port, out TcpClient client)
{
  try
  {
    client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(ip, port);
    IsConnected = true;
  }
  catch
  {
    logMan.WriteError($"Error reconnecting client for server [{ip}] on port [{port}]");
    client = null;
    IsConnected = false;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Check if there is connection
/// </summary>
public bool IsConnected { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Read the next line in the queue
/// </summary>
/// <returns>returns the next line in the queue</returns>
public string ReadLine()
{
  if (receivedQueue.Count > 0 && receivedQueue.TryDequeue(out string result))
  {
    return result;
  }

  return string.Empty;
}

/// <summary>
/// Write a message to the connection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">message</param>
public void Write(string message) =>
  sendQueue.Enqueue(message);
```

}